# How to fetch all ids of a column by matching with multiple columns of another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a user table and a team table. The team table consist of members from user table. Now the team table is carrying only ids and the user table holds the details of users. team table has four columns for ids of four members. Now how can I fetch the details from user table matching the ids of team table? I want to show the team list in a table with username of the members.

My user table - tbl_users
[image]

Team table - tbl_teams
[image]

I've tried like this, but I can't access the data to show in a single row.

```html
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>SL</th>
                  <th>Team Name</th>
                  <th>Team Leader</th>
                  <th>Member One</th>
                  <th>Member Two</th>
                  <th>Member Three</th>
                  <th>Member Four</th>
                  <th>Member Five</th>
                  <th>Member Six</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<?php

  $query = "SELECT tbl_teams.*, tbl_users.username FROM tbl_teams
            INNER JOIN tbl_users
            WHERE tbl_users.id IN (tLeader,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6)";
  
  $allprojects = $db->select($query);
  if ($allprojects) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($result = $allprojects->fetch_assoc()) {
      $i++;
?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['team_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['tLeader']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php } } ?>                
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: please add tables not as image see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You will want to take `tbl_teams` and use multiple left joins to match each team member to `tbl_users`

Comment: @KurtKline thanks for your reply. can you show me how to do this?

Comment: If you have the possibility, I think you can better change the database structure a bit and create a many to many table to connect a user to a team with there function or position. This way it will be more flexible to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. As mentioned in my comment, since you have the member ids spread out among multiple columns, the easiest way to achieve this is to have multiple left joins on `tbl_users`. By using a left join, you are maintaining all rows from the original table, while adding any necessary pieces of information.

```
select  t.*,
        l.username as L_username,
        u1.username as m1_username, 
        u2.username as m2_username, 
        u3.username as m3_username,
        u4.username as m4_username
from tbl_teams t 
left join tbl_users l on t.tLeader = l.id
left join tbl_users u1 on t.m1 = u1.id 
left join tbl_users u2 on t.m2 = u2.id 
left join tbl_users u3 on t.m3 = u3.id 
left join tbl_users u4 on t.m4 = u4.id
```

You can also play around with the code [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8uKg1ALc4Fcjfzm5sA1nrB/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT 
         T.*, 
         L.username as leader, 
         m1.username as member1, 
         m2.username as member2, 
         m3.username as member3, 
         m4.username as member4
FROM tbl_teams as T
INNER JOIN tbl_users as L ON L.id = T.tLeader
INNER JOIN tbl_users as m1 ON m1.id = T.m1
INNER JOIN tbl_users as m2 ON m2.id = T.m2
INNER JOIN tbl_users as m3 ON m3.id = T.m3
INNER JOIN tbl_users as m4 ON m4.id = T.m4";
```